# How can I log when a column is updated in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, logging

I'm having a problem with a database, where it seems a column is updated with a wrong value. At the moment, I have no idea which program is doing this. What would be the best way to find this out? Things that could really help me are, in order of helpfulness:

- The application name
- the host executing the application
- the exact SQL statement.

Could the transaction log help me here? Can I write a logging trigger somehow?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: SQL will only know as much about the calling application as it is provided with when the connection is opened. If that information is not provided in the connection string (explicitly or by default), you won't have it within SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a trigger and a table, along the lines of

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_foo_U On foo FOR UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

IF UPDATE(bar)
   INSERT logtable
   SELECT APP_NAME(), HOST_NAME(), SUSER_SNAME(), GETDATE(), * FROM INSERTED
GO
```

Comment: Don't forget getdate(), to track when the update was attempted!

Comment: @Philip Kelley: er... shall we say I assumed a column with a GETDATE() default in logtable :-)

Comment: Let's first declare: I don't know much about triggers. I get the following: `'UPDATED' is not a recognized built-in function name.
'USER_SNAME' is not a recognized built-in function name.` Any ideas? (further, I assume bar is the column name?)

Comment: And I think I need SUSER_SNAME() for the second one.

Comment: I can't edit your post, but I am going to accept it. Could you change UPDATED(bar) to UPDATE(bar), HOST_NAME to HOST_NAME() and USER_SNAME() to SUSER_SNAME()

Answer (score 1):

SQL profiler will give you this information, and I beleive you should be able to apply a filter such that you'd need to capture events on that particular object.

Comment: I tried adding a filter to the object (being the table name), but that didn't seem to filter anything. This is a rather busy production server, so manualy finding the offending statements would be like searching for a needle in a haystack. Where could I find more about filtering?

Comment: Certainly getting the profiling on the correct event, and with the right filters is tricky.  Depending on the event selected the objectID that you're interested in filtering on may or may not be known to the event.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303445

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the SQL Profiler to see all the activity going on against the database.